# how to create delete and move animations for listbox item

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, listboxitem

I'm looking for some animations for my listbox. When i swipe right on a listbox item, it goes to the bottom of the listbox and ideally, all the other listitems should gracefully go up. Similarly when I swipe left, that item gets deleted, and as before, the items needs to reposition.

I have implemented the functionality on swipe right and swipe left. But it is not graceful due to the lack of animations. How do I create those? Could someone share some blogs or msdn articles on how to create them. Or just give me some intro on this. I have never done animations before.

Thank you,

Comment: Try using Blend and create some static animations

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) has some transition effects that could help you. I assume you already know it since you implemented the swipe functionality unless you didn't use the provided gestures from it??

Comment: i havent used.. Gestures have been deprecated from the latest toolkit.